# Error: No Match for `Operator<<`

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So I'm creating this function as part of a larger program for my C++ course, and I am getting this error: `no match for 'operator<<'` followed by a bunch of gibberish whenever the compiler goes through this function

```
void print24hour(Time& start)
{
cout<<"The lecture starts at: ";
cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<< start.getHours <<":"<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<start.getMinutes<<":"<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<start.getSeconds;
}

void print24hour(Time& end)
{
cout<<" and ends at: ";
cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<end.getHours<<":"<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<end.getMinutes<<":"<<setfill('0')<<setw(2)<<end.getSeconds<<endl;
}
```

Any solutions to my problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You sure `Time::getHours` and `Time::getMinutes` aren't functions?

Comment: They are member functions for my Time class. Does this cause the problem?

Comment: What is the type of `Time::getHours`, `Time::getMinutes` and `Time::getSeconds`?

Comment: They return integers

Comment: ..so their type is probably `int()`. To get the return value you need to call them explicitly. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a function's *return value* you need to **call** it. Do this by appending parantheses to the member functions like `end.getMinutes()`.